# Flavored Activity can't be found on launch

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have created 2 flavors in Android Studio's Gradle, and I put the MainActivity file in their respective folder structures.

This is how the project looks:

[image]

This is the Gradle flavor part:

```
productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "com.xxxxx.yyyyy.free"
            versionName "1.0.0"
        }
        full {
            applicationId "com.xxxxx.yyyyy"
            versionName "1.0.0"
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, when I use the *full* flavor, the MainActivity is considered unset.

*Free* flavor:

[image]

*Full* flavor:

[image]

The project can be compiled in both flavors, it just can't be run on *full* flavor as it can't find the Default Activity.
The two files have minimal differences.

What should I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps not directly addressing your issue, but have you considered making a pure Java helper class that provides different functionality to your MainActivity?

The problem here appears to be your moving MainActivity is not being recognized by the AndroidManifest when in full mode, but if you have 2 versions of your helper class everything should be good

**Edit**
If you want to specify two different activities, use a relative path in your AndroidManifest.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
```

Be cautious to try and reuse as much common code as possible between your two activities to save yourself any headaches down the road though

Comment: My MainActivity files depend on different layout XML files, so I can't really sort it out with a pure helper class.

Comment: Is it just xml layout that's different between flavors? You can put your res/layout/foo.xml files under different flavor folders. MainActivity could check to see if certain views are available and adjust its behavior accordingly

Comment: But if the views are different, the view ids are also different, so MainActivity won't find the _R.id.viewInFree_ itself in full flavor.

Comment: You won't get an error for a missing view, findViewById will just return null

Comment: I'm concerned about the missing _id_, not the missing view. The generated _R.java_ shouldn't contain the _R.id.viewInFree_ as it is not part of the full flavored xml.

Comment: I added the MainActivity files again and applied the relative path, now it seems working okay.